# Select game scores with a player's context from Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am developing a web app with **rails** and **postgres** as a shooting range game backend. It has an endpoint to save players scores, which writes the scores to DB and returns the first three places and the players' ranks with some context around it: a place before and a place after. For example if a player has rank 23, the method should return 1st, 2nd, 3rd places, the player rank itself and also two records with ranks 22 and 24 besides it. I don't store the rank in the DB it is calculated dynamically using following **sql** query:

```
SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score DESC) AS place, name, score
FROM scores
WHERE game_id=? AND rules_version=? AND game_mode=?
LIMIT 10
```

`POST` request with following data:

```
{
  "players": [
    { "name": "Jack", "score": 100, "local_id": 1, "stats": {}},
    { "name": "Anna", "score": 200, "local_id": 2, "stats": {}}
  ]
}
```

should return following result set:

```
{
  "scores": [
    {
      "name": "Piter",
      "place": 1,
      "score": 800
    },
    {
      "name": "Lisa",
      "place": 2,
      "score": 700
    },
    {
      "name": "Philip",
      "place": 3,
      "score": 600
    },
    {
      "name": "Max",
      "place": 25,
      "score": 204
    },
    {
      "name": "Anna",
      "place": 26,
      "score": 200,
      "local_id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Ashley",
      "place": 27,
      "score": 193
    }
    {
      "name": "Norman",
      "place": 36,
      "score": 103
    },
    {
      "name": "Jack",
      "place": 37,
      "score": 100,
      "local_id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Chris",
      "place": 38,
      "score": 95
    }
  ]
}
```

Every field except `local_id` and as I said `place` is stored in DB. I can't figure out the right sql query to do such select. Please help.

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: I recommend to add the rank to your schema. I am guessing the rank is not changing that often and you are querying many times. So I would optimize for the read operations

Comment: What does Rails have to do with it?

Comment: @ArslanAli, if I won't be able to solve the problem using pure SQL I am going to do it programmatically with ruby.

Comment: So write models for the corresponding tables, and post 'em in question.